# Conditional attribute using thymeleaf

Tags: jsp, thymeleaf

I know how to make a conditional attribute inside a tag on jstl:

```
<body <c:if test="${userCreated}"> onload="somejavascriptfunction()"</c:if> >
```

But how do I do it using thymeleaf?

IndexController

```
@RequestMapping("/register")
public String register(UserEntity user, @RequestParam String repeatedPassword, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    user.setAdmin(false);
    userFacade.create(user);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(Constants.USER_CREATED, true);
    logger.info("Usuario criado");
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

So far the only solution I found was to do it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:if="${userCreated}">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     somejavascriptfunction()
  });
</script>
```

But that doesn't seem to be the best way to do it. So how do I make an if statement for an attribute on thymeleaf?

Comment: What you have is correct for attributes. Either the attribute isn't named the way you have it your the value isn't what you expect. I would do some debugging on the page. You have access to the HttpServletRequest in Thymeleaf ${#httpServletRequest} loop through all the attrbiutes and values

Comment: This is how I would debug it <body th:each="attribute : ${#httpServletRequest.getAttributeNames}">
 <p th:text="'Name: ' + ${attribute} + ' value: ' + ${#httpServletRequest.getAttribute(attribute)}"></p>
</body>

Comment: I don't think you understand, maybe I wasn't clear enough. From what I understood about Thymeleaf, you can only use th:if for tags not for tag attributes.
Now what I have is a conditional script tag, but that could be easily simplified if i could have a conditional onload attribute on my body tag.

Comment: Your right I was misunderstanding. You can do it for tag attributes example <div th:class="${userCreated} ? 'true' : 'false'"> Based on the boolean value of userCreated it assigned the div class to either true or false.... Now my question back to you is why are trying to execute some javascript onload? Thymeleaf renders everything server side and seems like your not using Thymeleaf to the full potential.

Comment: But how I would do that for onLoad attribute. Because when I "redirect:/login", I have a flag telling my view the user was created, so I can show a success box.

Comment: <div th:if="${userCreated == true}"><p>When userCreated is true anything inside this div is shown</p></div> Now that is pretty simple. I assume your looking for a modal box that your triggering by javascript. What we need to look at is the attributes of the modal when it is shown and hidden if you want to update your question.

Comment: That would kill the purpose of using a js lib for boxes. It's just weird it's mandatory to use a tag in order to use Thymeleaf methods/taglib or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: The way your using the js lib to popup a box on the page load, yes it does. Now I use bootstrap modals all the time to allow the user to edit and save information, in the page, but once the form is sent to the server and coming back using ajax. I have a div I use for successful and error messaging.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's really kind of counter-intuitive, considering to append a conditional class you use the following format:

```
<div th:classappend="${userSlug != null}?has-slug">
```

In order to append a conditional attribute, you put the condition on the attribute's value, like so:

```
<div th:attrappend="data-path=${userSlug != null}?@{/myaccount/__${userSlug}__}">
```

If userSlug is null, the previous statement will evaluate to:

```
<div>
```

If userSlug is *not* null, the statement evaluates to:

```
<div data-path="/myaccount/my-slug">
```

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried creating the onload attribute using the *th:attr* processor? I know there are several processors which will not render the attribute if the outcome is *null*. I'm not sure if this applies on the attr processor

```
<body th:attr="onload=${doOnload ? 'somejs()' : null}">
</body>
```

I dont have a testcode available here but this could work. Alternatively you could return an empty onload attribute.

Else, I don't see an issue with your second approach using a conditonal script tag. I do this quite often in my components.

Answer (score 7):

yorgos answer should be the accepted answer. I did the same with `disabled`

```
<div th:each="f, t : ${user1.folders}">
    <input th:attrappend="disabled=${user2.folders[__${t.index}__].closed?'disabled'}" />
</div>
```

PS: I don't have enough reputation to write a comment instead.

Comment: In general, if you want to leave a comment on an answer but you don't have enough reputation, do *not* post it as an answer. Instead, wait until you have 50 rep. Comments that are posted as answers because the user doesn't have enough rep are normally deleted. In this case, however, I think your answer is valid, because it's effectively proposing an alternative approach, so it's fine in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

The correct syntax is as follows:

```
th:attr="attributeName=${condition}? 'conditionIsTrue' : 'conditionIsFalse'"
```